# Change account type from terminal in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, permissions, users

How can I do by command line in terminal that an administrator should become standard (normal)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should change the group of that user with following command:

```
deluser --group [options] group
```

Man page says:

> **Remove a user from a specific group**
>
> If  called  with  two  non-option arguments, deluser will remove a user
>          from a specific group.